# Android StageFright Audio Loop Issue

Tags: android, audio, stagefright

I am having a big issue with recent updates to the android OS (specifically 3.2 on the Xoom) where using `MediaPlayer.setLooping(true)`; will no longer loop a `wav` or `ogg` file with a gap in between loops.

I have an application that requires a seamless loop and it has worked fine using the `OpenCore` framework, but I can't figure out how to get this to work on the new `StageFright` framework.  Can anyone give me a pointer on how to play a gapless audio loop using `StageFright` on newer versions of the Android  OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MediaPlayer` class for playback then you have no choice of using the media framework (`Opencore` Vs `Stagefright`). However if you have access to Android Source, then you can modify Android multimedia stack so that it uses `Opencore` framework for `ogg` / `wav` playback.

Now, if you have `ogg`/`wav` parser and `vorbis` decoder then you can make use of `AudioTrack` for playing audio out. The catch is that you have to take care of parsing and decoding; since `AudioTrack` accepts only `pcm` samples.

Shash